# Does this video show a very localised rain shower falling on one spot?

Tags: weather, video, meteorology

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ji6O5M1dFXs) has been doing the rounds<sup>*</sup> for the past couple of weeks, claiming it's a *very* local rain shower.

[image]

I find it hard to believe. A broken water mains or a geyser seems more likely. But the video perspective is not that you can say 'obviously fake'.

It does not help that the video often has been resampled and clipped - the linked one on YouTube was the best I could find so far.

Is this a rain formation?

<sup>* Search Youtube for 'rain falling on one spot' and you get these videos plus the ones about Togo. Search Facebook and you get a lot of other copies, one with 22 million and one with 70 millions views</sup>

Comment: I tried to unpause :/

Comment: ok, look at the shape of the water column. Look at where it "comes from". Notice how it "starts" in mid air, not in a cloud? It's not rain, it's water shooting up from somewhere on or under the ground.

Comment: Having been to Yellowstone and seen geisers go off from multiple angles, this looks exactly like an underground geiser.

Comment: Also it might be worth noting that none of the other cars passing by stop ever, nor does the person walking down the street seem all that interested. This implies to me that this is a relatively common occurrence at that location. Some sort of isolated rain shower definitely wouldn't be. An underground geyser though... that might be.

Answer (score 6):

### This is false.

The origin of this claim is this [video](https://youtu.be/5EZDtWyVawA) which shows water coming up from the ground not the sky. Snopes has an article debunking it.

> The video has been circulating online since at least June 2015, when
> it was shared under the title "Sources of water, water sources of well
> digging." While that version of the video did not include mention of a
> location, other postings of it have placed the incident in Indonesia,
> China, and Vietnam.
>
> This video also doesn't show "rain falling in one place." In fact, it
> doesn't show rain at all. The water in the video is coming up from the
> ground (not down from the sky), either from a natural geyser or a
> burst pipe.

The video OP posted was filmed on Akosombo Road in Ghana.

> A simliar shot of a burst high-pressure water main on Akosombo Road in
> Ghana has also been circulated with the same claim of its depicting
> "rain falling on only one spot"
>
> [Snopes | Rain mystery video](http://www.snopes.com/togo-rain-mystery-video/)

Comment: I am not convinced. The Togo video is a completely unrelated one (see vegetation and people). The Snopes link at the bottom of your answer has two video at the end claiming to be from the same incident, but their scale and time period differ too much. Don't get me wrong, I certainly don't believe this is local rainfall, but I see no proof of that.